# Safe async in a given scope

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to start an async coroutine with a suspending function in a given parent `CoroutineScope`, to produce a `Deferred` that might then be used from any coroutine in that scope.

I would like its job to be cancelled if the parent's job is cancelled, but if the suspending function throws an exception, I need that captured in the resulting `Deferred` without cancelling sibling jobs in the parent scope.

The way I'm doing it works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler, more idomatic way than this:

```
fun <T> callIt(scope: CoroutineScope, block: suspend () -> T) : Deferred<T> {
    val result = CompletableDeferred<T>()
    scope.launch {
        try {
            result.complete(block())
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            result.completeExceptionally(e)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I like that the handling of exceptions from the suspending `block` is obviously what I want, but I'm not too happy about building an `async` out of `launch`

Things that don't work:

- An async job with an exception handler.  `async` catches its exceptions, but the job still fails and cancels its parent.  As @Rene commented:  The documentation of `async` says: " it cancels the parent job (or outer scope) on failure to enforce structured concurrency paradigm.".

Comment: This would be more appropriate to ask over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without a `CompletableDeferred`. You need to create an [`SupervisorJob`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html) and let the job from the `CoroutineScope` be the parent of the new job. If the scope is cancelled the `async`-coroutine is cancelled as well. But no exception inside the `async`-coroutine will cancel the parent scope.

Because of an open issue https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1578 we need to explicitly complete the SupervisorJob.

```
fun <T> callIt(scope: CoroutineScope, block: suspend () -> T): Deferred<T> {
    val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob(scope.coroutineContext[Job])
    val deferred = scope.async(supervisorJob) {
        block()
    }
    deferred.invokeOnCompletion {
        supervisorJob.complete()
    }
    return deferred
}
```

Comment: But the `SupervisorJob` is a `CompletableJob` which will never be completed.  Won't that prevent its parent job from finishing?

Comment: I just wrote a test and it works. The parent coroutine is completed normally. BTW: Even the default job in the `CoroutineScope` is not completed (in your and mine solution). I registered a callback `invokeOnCompletion` on the job and it is never called. I have no Idea when `completed` is checked.

Comment: I wrote a test and it didn't work.  Maybe your parent scope had no job?  MCVE is `runBlocking {SupervisorJob(coroutineContext[Job])};println("never gets here")`

Comment: You shouldn't pass in a `Job` into `coroutineContext`. It should be passed via the scope.

Comment: @DominicFischer  that is retrieving the current Job from the current coroutineContext

Comment: (I see how it could be read that way). I meant you shouldn't pass an instance of `Job` into `async(....)` .

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes, I see now the same behavior as you. It never finishes. But the documentation  explicitly says use a `SupervisorJob` as parent.

Comment: Found exactly this issue: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1578

Comment: @Rene Thanks much for the pointer.  That works fine now.  I'll have to think about whether or not I like it better than my current implementation.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Can you share your ideas on this problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264148/how-to-answer-multiple-queries-for-an-array