# Kotlin coroutine exception handling - how to abstract the try-catch

Tags: exception, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to understand exception handling in Kotlin coroutines, so I came up with this very simple scenario where a network call throws an exception and my app has to catch it and handle it.

If I surround my async.await() call with a try-catch block, it works as intended. However, if I try to abstract that try-catch into an extension function, my app crashes.

What am I missing here?

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val job: Job = Job()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        runCode()
    }

    private suspend fun asyncCallThrowsException(): Deferred<Boolean> =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Thread.sleep(3000)// simulates a blocking request/response (not on the Main thread, though)
            throw(Exception())
        }

    suspend fun <T> Deferred<T>.awaitAndCatch() {
        try {
            this.await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("exception caught inside awaitAndCatch")
        }
    }

    private fun runCode() {
        scope.launch {

            //This block catches the exception.
            try {
                val resultDeferred = asyncCallThrowsException()
                resultDeferred.await()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("exception caught inside try-catch")
            }

            //This line does not, and crashes my app.
            asyncCallThrowsException().awaitAndCatch()
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I had actually forgotten to wrap the call inside an `async` block. Now, not even the explicit try-catch block works...

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class Main4Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val job: Job = Job()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + job)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        runCode()
    }

    private suspend fun callThrowsException(): String =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Thread.sleep(3000)// simulates a blocking request/response (not on the Main thread, though)
            throw(Exception())
            "my result"
        }

    suspend fun <T> Deferred<T>.awaitAndCatch(): T? {
        try {
            return this.await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("exception caught inside awaitAndCatch")
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun runCode() {
        scope.launch {

            val resultDeferred: Deferred<String> = async { callThrowsException() }
            var result: String?

//            This doesn't catch the throwable, and my app crashes - but the message gets printed to the console.
            try {
                result = resultDeferred.await()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("exception caught inside try-catch")
            }

//            This doesn't catch the throwable, and my app crashes - but the message gets printed to the console.
            result = resultDeferred.awaitAndCatch()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to a correct solution, the problem to solve is making it compatible with the principles of structured concurrency.

What exactly is your motivation to use `async`? What do you plan to do in the meantime, between launching the `async` and awaiting on it?

If both the `async` launch and the `await` call are a part of a single unit of work, and the success of the `async` call is a prerequisite to the overall success, then wrap the entire unit of work in `coroutineScope`.

If you want to launch this task in the background and await on it from an Android callback that is invoked later on, then this can't be encapsulated into a single unit of work. You should attach the async task to the top-level `CoroutineScope`, which should have a `SupervisorJob` in it.

The proper way to do this is shown in the [documentation of `CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/):

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
    override fun onDestroy() {
        cancel() // cancel is extension on CoroutineScope
    }

    ...
}
```

Kotlin standard library added the `MainScope()` delegate as a convenience so you don't get this wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The problem doesn't have to do with how you're catching the exception.  The problem is that when your async job fails (throws the exception), it cancels  the job you made for your activity.

Even though your code can catch the exception and print the message, the parent job will be terminated ASAP.

Instead of making it like this: `val: Job = Job()`, try `val: Job = SupervisorJob()`

A supervisor job isn't cancelled when its children fail, so this won't crash your app.

Or, if you want a way to start an async job that doesn't have this problem, see: [Safe async in a given scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229357/safe-async-in-a-given-scope)

Comment: I changed it to `SupervisorJob`, but the app crashed anyway. I had to pass a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to the scope to stop the app from crashing. I thought my extension function's `try-catch` would be enough if the scope had a `SupervisorJob`...

Comment: ps: with the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, both `Job` and `SupervisorJob` behave the same - the app doesn't crash.